# Retrieve different values from same table with different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to retrieve the date from a table with different conditions and put each different data with a sum in different columns. After a lot of testing I have this query, but its too slow and too big, and its not retrieving all units:

```
SELECT cal.dt, cal.h, a.measure, b.measure, c.measure, d.measure, e.measure, f.measure, g.measure, h.measure, ud.unit_name
FROM calendar cal
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date_bid, hour, ROUND(SUM(measure),3) as measure, id_unit, id_agent FROM MEASURES
    WHERE sesion = 0 AND date_bid BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013' GROUP BY date_bid, hour, id_unit, id_agent) a
    ON a.date_bid = dt AND a.hour = h
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date_bid, hour, ROUND(SUM(measure),3) as measure, id_unit, id_agent FROM MEASURES
    WHERE sesion = 1 AND date_bid BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013' GROUP BY date_bid, hora, id_unit, id_agent) b
    ON b.date_bid = dt AND b.hour = h AND a.id_unit = b.id_unit AND a.id_agent = b.id_agent
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date_bid, hour, ROUND(SUM(measure),3) as measure, id_unit, id_agent FROM MEASURES
    WHERE sesion = 2 AND date_bid BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013' GROUP BY date_bid, hour, id_unit, id_agent) c
    ON c.date_bid = dt AND c.hour = h AND a.id_unit = c.id_unit AND a.id_agent = c.id_agent
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date_bid, hour, ROUND(SUM(measure),3) as measure, id_unit, id_agent FROM MEASURES
    WHERE sesion = 3 AND date_bid BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013' GROUP BY date_bid, hour, id_unit, id_agent) d
    ON d.date_bid = dt AND d.hour = h AND a.id_unit = d.id_unit AND a.id_agent = d.id_agent
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date_bid, hour, ROUND(SUM(measure),3) as measure, id_unit, id_agent FROM MEASURES
    WHERE sesion = 4 AND date_bid BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013' GROUP BY date_bid, hour, id_unit, id_agent) e
    ON e.date_bid = dt AND e.hour = h AND a.id_unit = e.id_unit AND a.id_agent = e.id_agent
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date_bid, hour, ROUND(SUM(measure),3) as measure, id_unit, id_agente FROM MEASURES
    WHERE sesion = 5 AND date_bid BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013' GROUP BY date_bid, hour, id_unit, id_agent) f
    ON f.date_bid = dt AND f.hour = h AND a.id_unit = f.id_unit AND a.id_agent = f.id_agent
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date_bid, hour, ROUND(SUM(measure),3) as measure, id_unit, id_agente FROM MEASURES
    WHERE sesion = 6 AND date_bid BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013' GROUP BY date_bid, hour, id_unit, id_agent) g
    ON g.date_bid = dt AND g.hour = h AND a.id_unit = g.id_unit AND a.id_agent = g.id_agent
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date_bid, hour, ROUND(SUM(measure),3) as measure, id_unit, id_agent FROM MEASURES
    WHERE sesion = 7 AND date_bid BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013' GROUP BY date_bid, hour, id_unit, id_agent) h
    ON h.date_bid = dt AND h.hour = h AND a.id_unit = h.id_unit AND a.id_agent = h.id_agent
INNER JOIN FACILITIES ud ON a.id_unit = ud.id_unit
WHERE cal.dt BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013' AND a.id_agent = 42 
--GROUP BY a.date_bid, a.hour, ud.unit_name
ORDER BY cal.dt, ud.unit_name, cal.h
```

I tried before with **JOINS directly between the table without subselects** but didnt work because it can be different number of results for each `sesion`.

The problem now, apart from the significant amount of time of this query needs, is that is retrieving data only for the units that appears on the first subselect (`sesion = 1`), and when a unit has no data in there, is not showing the rest of the data.

I think there should be a better way to face this query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT  date_bid ,
            hour ,
            ROUND(SUM(measure), 3) AS measure ,
            id_unit ,
            id_agent, 
            sesion
    FROM    MEASURES
    WHERE   sesion BETWEEN 0 AND 7
            AND date_bid BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013'
    GROUP BY date_bid ,
            hour ,
            id_unit ,
            id_agent ,
            sesion
)
SELECT  cal.dt ,
        cal.h ,
        a.measure ,
        b.measure ,
        c.measure ,
        d.measure ,
        e.measure ,
        f.measure ,
        g.measure ,
        h.measure ,
        ud.unit_name
FROM    calendar cal
LEFT JOIN cte a ON a.date_bid = dt
    AND a.hour = h
    AND a.sesion = 0
LEFT JOIN cte b ON b.date_bid = dt
    AND b.hour = h
    AND a.id_unit = b.id_unit
    AND a.id_agent = b.id_agent
    AND b.sesion = 1
LEFT JOIN cte c ON c.date_bid = dt
    AND c.hour = h
    AND a.id_unit = c.id_unit
    AND a.id_agent = c.id_agent
    AND c.sesion = 2
LEFT JOIN cte d ON d.date_bid = dt
    AND d.hour = h
    AND a.id_unit = d.id_unit
    AND a.id_agent = d.id_agent
    AND d.sesion = 3
LEFT JOIN cte e ON e.date_bid = dt
    AND e.hour = h
    AND a.id_unit = e.id_unit
    AND a.id_agent = e.id_agent
    AND e.sesion = 4
LEFT JOIN cte f ON f.date_bid = dt
    AND f.hour = h
    AND a.id_unit = f.id_unit
    AND a.id_agent = f.id_agent
    AND f.sesion = 5
LEFT JOIN cte g ON g.date_bid = dt
    AND g.hour = h
    AND a.id_unit = g.id_unit
    AND a.id_agent = g.id_agent
    AND g.sesion = 6
LEFT JOIN cte h ON h.date_bid = dt
    AND h.hour = h
    AND a.id_unit = h.id_unit
    AND a.id_agent = h.id_agent
    AND h.sesion = 7
JOIN FACILITIES ud ON a.id_unit = ud.id_unit
WHERE cal.dt BETWEEN '02/27/2013' AND '02/28/2013'
    AND a.id_agent = 42 
--GROUP BY a.date_bid, a.hour, ud.unit_name
ORDER BY cal.dt ,
        ud.unit_name ,
        cal.h
```

Comment: Thanks but this query takes the same time as mine to retrieve the data and still has the problem about not taking some units (retrieve the same results as my query)